# Can anyone point me to an alternative for JavaEE SessionContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, cdi, jta

Within a Java EE context, specifically in a CDI [ApplicationScoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html) object, I need to force a rollback of a container-managed transaction. (it's a combination of a JPA (trans-)action and some filesystem action, the later is not really transactional, so I have to manually do some things)

I was able to use [SessionContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html) before, but after injection of some more dependencies, the framework (Weld CDI inside WildFly 8.1.0) does not mark my [ApplicationScoped](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/ApplicationScoped.html) object as a session- or message-driven bean anylonger. *(according to the error-message and most probably rightfully so)*

So the question is: is there an alternative? I did look into [UserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html), but is 'suffers' the same limitation as [SessionContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across [a post by Jaikiran Pai-2](http://wildfly-development.1055759.n5.nabble.com/Issues-accessing-UserTransaction-in-WildFly-tp5713802.html) which triggered me to look into the alternative called [TransactionSynchronizationRegistry](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/transaction/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry.html), argued to be the way to go in these situations. *(quote: Usage of this API is rarely explained and applications/libraries keep using UserTransaction instead.)*

I had to annotate the injection-point using this code:

```
@Resource(name = "java:comp/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry")
private TransactionSynchronizationRegistry transactionSynchronizationRegistry;
```

I tried it and it worked like a charm.